# Casting question in C#

Tags: c#, casting, covariance, contravariance

I have a interface that inherits from IList:

```
public interface IBase {}
public class Derived : IBase {}
public interface IMyList : IList<IBase> {}
```

I want to cast a variable of type `IMyList` to type `IList<Derived>` or `List<Derived>`, whichever is easier or makes the most sense. What's the best way to do this?

Note that I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: As others have mentioned, that conversion is never legal, and for good reasons. To help you find a workaround, it would be helpful to know what you are going to do with the IList<Derived> when you have it. For example, is it going to be read-only when you get it, or are you going to try to add items to it, or what? If you are just reading it, are you using "random" access, or always iterating the whole thing from start to finish with "foreach"?  Are you using LINQ queries on it?  And so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A direct cast isn't going to be suitable since there are numerous problems that could occur (`IMyList` may contain types other than `Derived`, etc.)

As long as you're not modifying the list (in which case, `IEnumerable<Derived>` would work) you could simply:

```
var validItems = myList.Cast<Derived>();
```

And then iterate over the result.

**Edit**

Based on the OP's comment below, there are two other things to mention:

1) If you need an `IList<Derived>`, you could simply add to the above and call `myList.Cast<Derived>().ToList();`

2) If those are truly the requirements, then your code doesn't make any sense. If `IMyList` should only ever contain `Derived` objects then `IMyList` should derive from `IList<Derived>`. Remember that while you know that there is only one type implementing the `IBase` interface, the compiler doesn't so be specific.

Using interfaces everywhere just for the sake of using interfaces doesn't help anybody!

Comment: This won't work. The end result absolutely has to be at least an `IList<>` because I am passing the casted result into a function that takes an `IList<Derived>`. I can also guarantee that the `IMyList` list will never have anything other than `Derived` in it because it's the only class that inherits from `IBase`

Comment: @Robert Dailey - If those are the requirements, then your code doesn't make sense. If IMyList should only contain Derived objects, it should inherit from IList<Derived> rather than IList<IBase>.

Comment: Basically we have our project setup to build the "concrete" types into a separate assembly than the interface types to avoid circular reference issues. `IMyList` is defined in the "interfaces assembly", which does not have a reference to the "concrete assembly" where `Derived` is defined, so `IMyList` *must* inherit from `IList<IBase>`.

Comment: @Robert: You can't expect the compiler (or runtime) to know that. The compiler reasonably assumes that you are using interfaces for their *intended* purpose, namely to have two or more *unrelated* classes implement the same functionality. A "list of interface" can reasonably be expected to contain objects of multiple unrelated types, and therefore cannot *ever* be treated as "list of one specific type".

Comment: @Eric I understand that as a general principle but I can make certain safe assumptions that you may not understand, since my original question is very much out of context.

Comment: @Robert: I understand that *you* can reason logically about the type safety of your program. But making *the compiler* reason perfectly logically about the type safety of your program *is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem*. There are type systems that you can force to attempt to solve the Halting Problem. The Haskell type system is one but the C# type system is not.

Comment: @Eric But I'm not trying to make a compiler. I am taking my assumptions and coding the logic for those assumptions using the compiler as-is. I don't really understand what your point is. I don't want to change how the compiler behaves.

Comment: @Robert - His point is that the cast you want to make can't be done safely because the compiler can't infer the rules that you are going by.

Comment: Well thanks for the help guys. I realize what I'm doing is WRONG, I realized that before I ever started writing this question. However, unfortunately this is company code and the current design & architecture of the system and how we decouple objects cannot be changed. So, I'm having to find quirky workarounds for things that should be non-issues, and I hate asking for how to be evil >:)

Comment: @Robert Then you have to get a step in between where you create a new `List<Derived>` and copy the entire `List<Base>` into it by casting each object. LINQ can do that using the `OfType` and `Cast` extension methods.

Comment: @Michael: The problem with that approach is that (1) it is expensive if the list is large and (2) if the callee is making edits to the list -- and if they're not, then why are they demanding an IList instead of an IEnumerable? -- then how are the edits going to be copied back to the original list? An alternate technique is to create a proxy object that fixes up accesses to the original list to be of the right element type.

Comment: @Eric I use an `IList<T>` indeed because `RemoveAt()` is called on it under certain conditions.

Comment: @Robert: Then you should not be using any technique that involves making a copy of the list -- like doing a Cast<> followed by a ToList(). You're probably going to have to make a proxy that puts casts on top of every interface method call.

Answer (score 4):

> I am passing the casted result into a function that takes an `IList<Derived>`.

Then you are in a world of pain of your own devising. My advice would be first to find some other way to solve your circular dependency problem. Making everything into interfaces that have only one possible implementation is a painful way to solve that problem, as you have discovered. I don't recommend it.

If you can't do that then I would try to fix the offending function so that it either takes an `IList<IBase>`, an `IEnumerable<IBase>` or an `IEnumerable<Derived>`.  Preferably one of the IEnumerable solutions; most methods that take *lists* in fact only need *sequences*. If you could explain why you need a list here, that would be helpful in trying to find a workaround.

If you can make it take an `IList<IBase>` or `IEnumerable<IBase>` then you're done; you already have something in hand that is implicitly convertible to the desired type.

If you can make it take an `IEnumerable<Derived>` then you can say `myListOfIBase.Cast<Derived>()` (if you really know that all of them are Derived) or `myListOfIBase.OfType<Derived>()` (if you suspect that some of them might not be of type Derived and want to skip them) and get an `IEnumerable<Derived>` that efficiently uses the underlying list.

If you cannot change the offending function then you can make your own class that efficiently uses the underlying list:

```
sealed class MyProxyList : IList<Derived>
{
    IList<IBase> underlyingList;
    public MyProxyList(IList<IBase> underlyingList)
    {
        this.underlyingList = underlyingList;
    }
    ... now implement every member of IList<Derived> as 
    ... a call to underlyingList with a cast where necessary 
}
```

And then pass a new `MyProxyList` to the method.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 3.5 does not have generic covariance.  To demonstrate:

```
[TestFixture]
class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
        var list = new List<SuperClass>();
        list.Add(new SuperClass());

        var castedList = ((List<BaseClass>)list);
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public string a { get; set; }
}

public class SuperClass : BaseClass
{
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

Will not compile successfully.

In Justin Niessner's response, the work around

```
var validItems = myList.Cast<Derived>();
```

was posted.  This will work but will result in an enumeration of the entire list (although this enumeration is deferred) and also return an enumerable.  To convert the list and end up with an IList you can use the following

```
[Test]
public void CanConvertListToBaseClass()
{
    var list = new List<SuperClass>();
    list.Add(new SuperClass());

    var castedList = list.Cast<BaseClass>().ToList();
    Assert.That(castedList, Is.InstanceOf<IList<BaseClass>>());
}
```

This is a pretty brute-force approach however.  This will result in a new and separate IList and will force an enumeration of the entire list.

Comment: I took quite a bit of time before posting this to understand the covariance/contravariance issues in .NET 3.5. This is why I posted the question because I am uncertain of the proper solution for this. Thanks for the heads up, though!

Comment: Robert Dailey: I know that this anwser is common (and seemingly hated) but you may want to rethink your approach.  I don't think there IS a proper solution.  I can think of some really terrible workarounds but nothing that seems any decent.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a design I can't fix, which is why I'm trying to solve the problem this way. This is company code and is already "established", so changing the design isn't an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Since `IList<T>` allows read *and* write operations of type `T`, the interface is neither co- nor contravariant. Thus, what you want cannot be done. Imagine the following code:

```
var myList = new MyListImlementation();
myList.Add(new BaseImplementation());
var castList = (IList<Derived>)myList; // this is what you want

// this would break, because myList contains elements of type BaseImplementation.
Derived d = castList[0];
```

Comment: I did not state this originally, but `Derived` is the only class that inherits/implements `IBase`, so this is a non-issue. There is no possible way to cause a runtime error with my current hierarchy.

Comment: @Robert: if Derived is the only class that implements IBase then why do you need IBase in the first place? Simply replace every instance of "IBase" in your program with "Derived", done, problem solved.

Comment: @Eric See my comments on the highest rated answer. It explains the reasoning behind this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be absolutely certain going forward that all instances will be of type `Derived`, then you can use `Cast<>()`, with the performance issues noted earlier.  If there is a chance that something besides `Derived` will ever be in the list, then you'll want to use `OfType<Derived>()` instead.  Non-`Derived` items would be excluded instead of throwing.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do this in .Net 3.5, but you can in .Net 4.0.

Comment: You can't even in 4.0. `IList<T>` does not support it.

Comment: -1: This answer isn't helpful at all and doesn't even answer my original question.